# Reduce array "resolution" in LabView

Tags: arrays, labview

Really simple question, I just can't get around this visual programming. I have an array of size 600. I want to reduce it to a size of 10 by grabbing a number every 60 index of the array. I know how to do this in a normal programming language, but I can't figure out LabView. Can anyone have pity and help me out? I've attached where I'm at so far, but it's sad.

[image]

Comment: Tip: You don't need to declare the 'Array' before adding data to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have would be a good way to do this if you needed a fixed sized array. This would be important if you are running on an FPGA or need to reduce jitter on an RT target.

What you have is not the easiest way to do this. Any easier way would be to accumulate your new array with a shift register like so:

[image]

As you can see- if the index is a multiple of 60 then the element is appended to the array. Otherwise, in the false case, the array is passed through unmodified.

You should know that, although this method is much easier to use, it will occasionally cause memory allocations to increase the size of the array being accumulated. Usually that isn't a problem.

Answer (score 9):

Since the size is known, it's much more efficient to do something like this:

[image]

You can also configure the output tunnel to be conditional, which makes the code simpler, but not as efficient, because it has to repeatedly allocate memory. This isn't really a consideration when you have an array with 10 elements, but it could be with larger arrays:

[image]

If you're having trouble with something like this, you might wish to go through some tutorials, books or even courses.

Comment: It won't reallocate with every call of course. It will allocate in spurts. I do like your index array solution better-no sense running the loop n times when you only need n/60.

Comment: Not exactly. In 2012, it behaves just like your code, which I believe allocates with every call. I believe that in 2013 it's supposed to behave more like auto-indexing out of a while loop, which does allocate exponentially. In any case, this is an implementation detail.  I also wouldn't say there was no sense in doing this - some people might find the code simpler and it might be acceptable to choose that over the more efficient code under specific circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach (without loops):

[image]

I reshape the array into a 2d array (this will not allocate a new Array, only the dimensions will be altered), then index out the first coloumn to get every 60th element.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you cold do this is to use the [decimate 1-d array](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361H-01/glang/decimate_1d_array/) primitive.

Which split the array up into `n` fixed length arrays where the first array contains the `0 n 2n 3n ...` Although it might be a bit large for n=60.

This would probably be more useful if you needed multiple arrays of same length that just started at different positions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you describe, you might want to do something like take the mean of each 60 values instead of just arbitrarily grabbing each 60th, that way you aren't showing a lot of jitter if you happen to grab an outlier.  This may or may not make sense depending on your application:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also consider checking out the open source [OpenG toolkit](http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/209027).  It has a function called "Index 1D array elements" for indexing arrays where you simply give it the array and the index locations of the desired data, and it returns the desired reduced array.  Note that if you start dealing with extremely large arrays, its functions might be too slow and/or memory intensive, but it also contains a lot of great functions, not just for array manipulation.